# Compact manifolds can almost be immersed?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, differential-topology

The Whitney Immersion theorem states that any $n$-dimensional manifold can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

However, I seem to remember that if $X$ is a compact $n$-dim manifold, then $X$ can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$, except at possibly some finite number of places. Does anyone have a reference of where a proof of this result may be found?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but is there a mistake in the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_immersion_theorem ? Because that article claims there is a smooth (not necessarily injective) immersion of any smooth $n$-dimensional manifold into $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$, and the embedding theorem says it can be smoothly *embedded* in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. I expect one can find this in the original work of Whitney.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, every smooth compact $n$-manifold ($n\ge 2$) admits an immersion in $R^{2n-1}$. This result was proven by H.Whitney in "The singularities of a smooth $n$-manifold in $(2n − 1)$-space", Ann. of Math. (2), 45 (1944) pp. 247-293.

This result was improved rather dramatically by R.Cohen in 1982 (see an outline  here http://www.pnas.org/content/79/10/3390.full.pdf), full proof is in

Ralph L. Cohen "The Immersion Conjecture for Differentiable Manifolds", 
Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 122, No. 2 (1985), pp. 237-328.

Cohen proved that every smooth compact $n$-manifold admits an immersion in $R^{2n -a(n)}$, where $a(n)$ is the number of 1's in the binary expansion of $n$, $n>1$.

Comment: Thanks for the source, studiosus.

Comment: Can we further improve the codimension if we know that X is a vector bundle of low rank (say 8)?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: You should ask a new question.